# SharePoint 2010 custom search from Layouts page

Tags: sharepoint, search

I am querying SharePoint 2010 search using FullTextSqlQuery. The query returns results as long as i run it from the webpart. However, for some reason, i need to run the same query from a custom aspx page deployed under layouts. The query returns a wcf exception.

Has anyone tried running custom queries from pages deployed to layouts folder under 14 hive?

Thanks,
Faiz

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find the reason. In the custom webpart, the RowLimit propery of Query was being set to 25. However, in the layouts page, the limit was set to 2000. I noticed that SharePoint 2010 custom search by default takes for the RowLimit property, a maximum value of 500.

Cheers.